# Terminal command to output as csv with two columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I've have an awk script in terminal where it performs some counting function:

```
awk '{ a[$2]++ }END{ for(i in a) printf "%-15s%s\n",i,a[i] }'   
Data_1
```

and i plan to output as a csv file where i add

```
awk '{ a[$2]++ }END{ for(i in a) printf "%-15s%s\n",i,a[i] }'    
Data_1 > Count.csv
```

but the problem I'm facing now is, the awk script above outputs

```
Gregor   4
Alexis   15
George   17
```

and after outputting as a csv file, the name and count is appended to only one column A in excel. How would i format the csv command in terminal to specify the name to have one column and the number in another column? In excel I want to obtain

```
A         B
Gregor    4
Alexis    15
George    17
```

Comment: Try adding `OFS` into your code.

Comment: What symbol do you use as delimeter in csv?

Answer (score 3):

You need add a comma between fields to have simple `.csv` type format when you are using with `printf`.

```
awk '{ a[$2]++ }END{ for(i in a) printf "%-15s,%s\n",i,a[i] }'
Gregor    ,4
Alexis    ,15
George    ,17
```

Or full-fledged .csv type

```
awk '{ a[$2]++ }END{ for(i in a) printf "\"%-15s\",\"%s\"\n",i,a[i] }'
"Gregor    ","4"
"Alexis    ","15"
"George    ","17"
```

But you could use `print` instead and let `awk` add comma with `OFS` (simple .csv).

```
awk '{ a[$2]++ }END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i] }' OFS=,
Gregor,4
Alexis,15
George,17
```

Or just print it within fields itself.

```
awk '{ a[$2]++ }END{ for(i in a) print i","a[i] }'
Gregor,4
Alexis,15
George,17
```

For full-fledged .csv format.

```
awk '{ a[$2]++ }END{ for(i in a) print "\""i"\",\""a[i]"\"" }'
"Gregor","4"
"Alexis","15"
"George","17"
```